# problem in adding a new item to a To Do List react app

Tags: reactjs

in this piece of code on react i'm trying to add new items to my to do list but it doesn’t work and i can not understand why.can someone please tell me why the out put of this piece code i wrote is an empty array?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function AddNote() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState("");
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");

  const inputArray = [];

  function saveInput(event) {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  }

  function addNewItem() {
    setItem(itemName);
    inputArray.push(item);
    setInput("");
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="form">
        <input onChange={saveInput} type="text" value={input} />
        <button onClick={addNewItem}>
          <span>Add</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {inputArray.map(toDOItem => {
            return <li>{toDOItem}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddNote;
```

Comment: The `inputArray` is not something that is persisted across re-renders. It is declared empty, and every time the component renders again ( when state change ), it will be declared empty again. If you want your `inputArray` to retain its value across the life cycle of your component, you need to make sure it's stored as part of the state of the component. The same way you do with `useState` from `item` and `input` - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: In the beginning, read the reactjs.org document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since function-components are just functions that are run each time state changes, and the `inputArray` variable is declared every time React re-renders your function, it will never appear to change.

1. Your component renders the first time and `inputArray` is defined and set to `[]`. An `addNewItem` function is defined and bound to the `onClick` event for a `<button>`.
2. The `<button>` is clicked, calling the previously defined `addNewItem` which holds a reference to `inputArray` (it's a closure). This `addNewItem` calls two state-setting functions, prompting React to queue two more renders of the component.
3. React re-renders the component the first time with the new `itemName` value. An `inputArray` variable is defined, as is a new `addNewItem` function. Step 1 fully repeats.
4. React re-renders the component a second time with the new `input` value. As in #1 and #3 above, a new `inputArray` is defined and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The `inputArray` also needs to be stored in state; it's not persisted across renders by default:

```js
function AddNote() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState("");
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [inputArray, setInputArray] = useState([]);

  function saveInput(event) {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  }

  function addNewItem() {
    setItem(itemName);
    setInputArray(arr => [...arr, item]);
    setInput("");
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove setItem from addditem and add that setItem (input) in saveInput..